# How to move marker with animation from one location to another smoothly in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, html, function, openlayers-3

I want to move a marker with animation from one location to another smoothly in openlayer. There is a sample:
http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html. But this has a polyline coordinates which consist of different characters. I want to move a marker with animation from one location (lat1,lon1)  to new place (lat2,lon2) . I haven't find this for weeks. Pls help me.